# VS15 Azure webapp remote debug can't find <project>.dll symbol file

Tags: c#, azure, debugging, pdb-files

Here is where it looked

```
  D:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\EchoLink.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    D:\local\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\666e113f\f37e3090\assembly     
    \dl3\62af14e3\107ea37a_935fd201\EchoLink.pdb: Cannot find or open the     DB        file.
    C:\Users\Coder\Dropbox\CognitiveCode\Code\EchoLink\EchoLink\obj\Release    \EchoLink.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    C:\WINDOWS\EchoLink.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    C:\WINDOWS\symbols\dll\EchoLink.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    C:\WINDOWS\dll\EchoLink.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    C:\Users\Coder\Documents\CacheFolderVS15\EchoLink.pdb    \d02dfc307a074c5f8a7b8eb55059e5b91\EchoLink.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB     file.
    C:\Users\Coder\Documents\CacheFolderVS15\MicrosoftPublicSymbols\EchoLink.pdb    \d02dfc307a074c5f8a7b8eb55059e5b91\EchoLink.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file.
SYMSRV:  C:\Users\Coder\Documents\CacheFolderVS15\EchoLink.pdb\D02DFC307A074C5F8A7B8EB55059E5B91\EchoLink.pdb - file not found
*** ERROR: HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND
*** ERROR: HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND
*** ERROR: HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND
SYMSRV:  C:\Users\Coder\Documents\CacheFolderVS15\EchoLink.pdb\D02DFC307A074C5F8A7B8EB55059E5B91\EchoLink.pdb not found
SYMSRV:  https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols/EchoLink.pdb/D02DFC307A074C5F8A7B8EB55059E5B91/EchoLink.pdb not found
https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols: Symbols not found on symbol server.
```

when compiling this Class Library, it will compile fine in local mode, but when I try to compile for remote debug with Azure, neither the computer, nor I, can find the dll and pdb files necessary for remote debug.

Answer (score 0):

> when compiling this Class Library, it will compile fine in local mode, but when I try to compile for remote debug with Azure, neither the computer, nor I, can find the dll and pdb files necessary for remote debug.

As far as I know, `{project}.dll` and `{project}.pdb` files are in **bin** folder. And Symbol files (stored in PDB files) are required for your application and for any third-party or system DLLs you have to debug. If required Symbol files could not be found or opened, remote debug will fail. Please check whether you specify the files that you want to be loaded automatically in Tools / Options / Debugging / Symbols.

[image]

And Visual Studio enable us to specify a directory where symbol files are located and symbols cache directory,  and from [this documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241613.aspx), we could find that symbol cache should not be placed in a protected folder.

> Note
>
> Do not place your symbol cache in a protected folder (such as the C:\Windows folder or one of its subfolders). Use a read-write folder instead.